# Equivalent Curl Request

Tags: ruby, curl

What is the equivalent cURL request to this test?

```
test "create user" do
        user = {
            user: {
                username: "fasfas",
                password: "fasfas",
                password_confirmation: "fasfas",
                email: "fasfas@fasfas.com"
            }
        }
        post "/users", user, {"Accept" => "application/json"}
        assert_equal response.status, 201
    end
```

I was trying something like

```
curl http://someurl.com/users -d "username=...&password=..."
```

and so on, but it don't works because controller requires the `user` param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
curl -X POST -d "user[username]=fasfas&user[password]=fasfas&user[password_confirmation]=fasfas&user[email]=fasfas@fasfas.com" http://someurl.com/users
```

Comment: It worked! Btw, I read in other questions that if you use `-d` option, you don't need to specify the POST method. Anyways, thanks fella!